# HTML writing number of php while iterations on page

Tags: php, html, while-loop

I have a tiny while loop on my page, but it's also writing every iteration of the loop on my page, and I want those iterations (marked on the screenshot) to be not shown, here is the code:

```
while ($i < ($blocksize / 2) - 1) {?>
    <span class="nowrap"><?= $a.','.$b;?></span>
    <?= $a++; $b--; $i++;?>
    <span class="nowrap"><?= $b.','.$a;?></span>
    <?= $a++; $b--; $i++;?>
<?php };?>
```

And the output screenshot:
Output

[image]

Please help me to solve this problem, Thanks everyone!

Comment: _"Please help me to solve this problem"_ - What problem? You've just shown us some code and what output it gives you. You need to explain what result you're expecting or we won't have a clue. You also need to let us know what all those unknown variables contains.

Comment: I need to get rid of that iterations, which I have marked on the output screenshot, thanks.

Comment: Remove the echoes`<?= $a++; $b--; $i++;?>` to `<?php $a++; $b--; $i++;?>`. `<?=` is the same as `<?php echo `.

Comment: Working, thank you, can you post this as answer please?

Comment: I've posted an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `<?=` for the values you don't want to output. `<?=` is short hand for `<?php echo`.

If you just want to execute a statement but not output anything, just use `<?php`.

So change

```
<?= $a++; $b--; $i++;?>
```

to

```
<?php $a++; $b--; $i++;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while ($i < ($blocksize / 2) - 1) {?>
    <span class="nowrap"><?= $a.','.$b;?></span>
    <?php $a++; $b--; $i++;?> // remove = here
    <span class="nowrap"><?= $b.','.$a;?></span>
    <?php $a++; $b--; $i++;?> //remove = here
<?php };?>
```

Comment: I would recommend to always use `<?php` instead of short tags `<?`, since they have been disabled by default since a bunch of years back.